# Kustomize HTTP resource with patch not working

Tags: kustomize

I have a Kustomize v5.0.0 project with the following layout:

```
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── foo
│       ├── kustomization.yaml
│   
│
└── overlay
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    ├── foo
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        ├── deployment-patch.yaml
```

In `base/kustomization.yaml` I define a HTTP resource and the subdirectory where I have a specific new app for the overall environment. The plan is to add more apps, hence these subdirs:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acme/myproject/v1.2.3/manifest.yaml
  - foo
```

In `base/foo` I define a new manifest such as an ingress that I add to the environment contained within the HTTP resource.

In `overlay/kustomization.yaml` I reference the overlay subdirs as such:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - foo
```

In `overlay/foo/kustomization.yaml` I reference the base and include an environment-specific patch (dev vs. prod etc.). The deployment in question is in the HTTP resource and has a unique name (there is no other deployment with the same name).

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base/foo


patches:
 - target:
     kind: Deployment
     name: some-unique-name
   path: deployment-patch.yaml
```

1. With the HTTP resource defined in the base, it is not loaded when I build the overlay. What is wrong with my setup?
2. If I move the HTTP resource into `overlay/kustomization.yaml` and comment out the patch instruction, then I can see the HTTP resource is loaded. However, including the patch gives the error: `... failed to find unique target for patch ...`. The deployment information in the patch matches a unique deployment in the HTTP resource via `kind` and `name`. Why does this fail? Is it because the HTTP resource is defined in the `kustomization.yaml` of the parent directory to `foo`? I created the structure I have as I will have multiple overlays for different environments, and in each I will have patches for different applications, each defined in a separate child directory of the overlay directory.

Comment: This sort of question is a lot easier to answer if it includes a [mcve]. Use real data, rather than fake/obfuscated links. If you can't show the actual repository, then create one (or a gist!) with sample data sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're including the remote `http://...` resource in `base/kustomization.yaml`, but in `overlay/foo/kustomization.yaml` you are explicitly including `../../base/foo`...so you completely bybass `../../base/kustomization.yaml`.

That's why you don't see the remote resource in your output.